# split string in xsl and update attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a xml file with below structure

```
    <project>
    <dependency id="abc" version="1.2.3.4"/>
    </project>
```

I need to read this xml and update another xml with the value of id and version. Earlier i did this with an xsl like below, which was working fine:

```
    <xsl:attribute name="id">
    <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
    </xsl:attribute>

    <xsl:attribute name="version">
    <xsl:value-of select="@version"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
```

Now I need to set the attribute value of version as [1.2,1.3), how can I do this? I tried something like this below, but I dont think I'm getting no where.

```
    <xsl:variable name="MinVersion"/>
    <xsl:variable name="MaxVersion"/>

<xsl:for-each select="tokenize(@version,'.')">

<xsl:if test="(position( )) = 2">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($MinVersion,.)"/>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($MinVersion,.,'.')"/>
</xsl:otherwise>

<xsl:if test="(position( )) = 2">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($MaxVersion,number(.)+1)"/>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($MaxVersion,.,'.')"/>
</xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

How can I do this?

UPDATE: I tried to debug this in Visual Studio and got error message stating tokenize is not a recognized function. After some searching found .NET framework supports only XSLT 1.0 processor. Any solution with 1.0 would be helpful.

Comment: Should your output be like follows: [$MinVersion - Firstnumber.Secondnumber]  [$MaxVersion- Firstnumber.Thirdnumber] ? should it always follow this pattern ?

Comment: Microsoft's XSLT processors in the .NET framework (i.e. `XslCompiledTransform` and `XslTransform`) are XSLT 1.0 processors but there are third party XSLT 2.0 processors like the .NET version of Saxon 9 http://saxon.sourceforge.net/#F9.4HE or AltovaXML (usable in .NET via COM interop) or XmlPrime. So that way you can use the `tokenize` function in XSLT with .NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following, Hope it will solve your problem.(I have Changed my prevous answer, check following new one.)

```
<xsl:variable name="testVersion" select="@version"></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="separator" select="'.'"></xsl:variable>


<xsl:if test="string-length($testVersion) > 0">

  <xsl:variable name="firstnumber"     select="substring-before($testVersion, $separator)"/>
  <xsl:variable name="after-separator" select="substring-after($testVersion, $separator)"/>       
  <xsl:variable name="secondnumber"    select="substring-before($after-separator, $separator)"/>        

  <xsl:variable name="outputvalue">
    <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$firstnumber"></xsl:value-of>
    <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$secondnumber"></xsl:value-of>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$firstnumber"></xsl:value-of>
    <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="number($secondnumber)+1"></xsl:value-of>
    <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:value-of select="$outputvalue"/>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Madurika: The output should always be in the following pattern, assuming @version is 1.1.234.5678 I need a value in a variable like below: [firstnumber.secondnumber, firstnumber,secondnumber+1) 
I'll check the substring option, if the firstnumber is 2 digit number, I guess the proposed solution might fail. Let me check it out though

Martin: Saxon is not an feasible option right now, because this will be called inside an MSBuild script.

Comment: @KarunakaranPannirSelvam There is no problem calling Saxon from within an MSBuild script. You can use the console version of Saxon.

Comment: @Karun please be kind enough to up vote for the answer by clicking up arrow head. .... cheers....!!!!!

Comment: I tried to up vote, looks like I need more reputation to do that.